# Form submit in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I put a search box in the layout file so that all the pages that use the layout has the layout. When the user clicks on the button to search, where do I handle the submit/action from this form?

How does this suppose to work for actions initiated from the _Layout.cshtml page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no different than using a form in an ordinary view. You just have to write an action that will respond to the POST request and make sure the form is posted to that action.

In _Layout.cshtml

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    ...
}
```

Inside HomeController (it can be any other controller)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
    {
        //search implementation
    }        
}
```